# I would like music to play on the main page of my website. What is the beginner way to do this?

Tags: audio, mp3, playback

I am making a basic website and I'd like to make some (obnoxious I know) music play on the first page of the website. I'm very new to all this so really - if I can get any music to play at all just on the main page that'd be awesome.

I have an MP4, MP3 and an Ogg file of the music. I've tried a few tricks that people addressed on other questions here but I haven't seemed to get anything to work.

A question I have specifically is - where do you put the file? I have it in my folder like "mystupidproject/audio/mpeg/kokomo.mp3" Is there another way I am supposed to be doing this? Then, I seem to get the music play button to pop up with some of the audio tricks previously discussed on this site but then the music never actually plays.

What is the easiest way to integrate music into a site even if it just plays once on the main page? I dont even care if you can turn it off or not.

What is the easiest way to integrate obnoxious music into the index page of a site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

    <audio controls autoplay hidden="hidden">
      <source src="audio/mpeg/kokomo.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
      <source src="audio/mpeg/kokomo.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>

    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the main directory;

[image]

And file locations;

```
mystupidproject\index.html
mystupidproject\audio\mpeg\kokomo.mp3
```

Comment: @Dolphins : If it worked for you, I'm so glad for it :)